# R: how to perform fread() with patterns in datatable?

Tags: r, datatable, pattern-matching, fread

I'd like to know using `windows` **(not linux)** if there any possibilities to perform `fread` with `patterns` in `r` to selectively import or read a portion of a large file?

as an example , I am trying to only read/select the rows with `6/5/2017` and `14/5/2017` from a `temp.csv` file with `fread` in `windows` OS. I use the following but it dose not work!

```
fread("./temp.csv",patterns = "^[6,14]/2/2017")
```

Any help with explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no pattern matching in `fread` as far as I know. If your data file is large then you can read the data in chunks by using `nrows` and `skip` options and filter the data based on the pattern and use `rbindlist` to join them all.

Comment: A common answer in selecting rows on reading in data in R is to use `read.csv.sql` from the `sqldf` package and add a where statement in the sql query.

Comment: @lmo `read.csv.sql` is at least two orders of magnitude slower than `fread`, so is not an option. Is there any faster alternative to `read.csv.sql`?

Comment: @MoyseyAbramowitz If you use Linux, you can pair `fread` with command line tools line `grep` and `sed`. These tools can be quite fast. This is done through the `cmd` argument. I suspect this argument will also work for windows with DOS-like commands though I haven't tried it.